Java application using Dropwizard respond with 502 on higher load
i have some Java applications running inside Docker containers using the Dropwizard framework (Jetty, etc.) There is also an Nginx als reverse-proxy put in front of them. Each container has a different job and are interconnected. Some containers run on the same Docker host, others on different.
Now, as the load of users increase, i find more and more 502 errors logged from Nginx, together with "premature closed connection" and "connection reset by peer" messages in the Nginx errorlog. This means Nginx sometimes cannot access the upstream containers. This happens inbetween other requests going through without issues.
I do not find errors/drops logged in the Java applications themselfs, and so i suspect that something else is going wrong at that time. How can i find out how many requests such a container can process without issues and with might be the bottleneck on network level?
